# Need held with scala compile time error when defining a lagom service implementation

Tags: scala, lagom

I've been using lagom with Java for some time without problems, but am struggling to get it to work with scala (disclosure - since I am
fairly new to scala, I am probably doing something daft).

I have defined a (very) minimal lagom service (below) which should not cause 
any problems, but I am getting the scala compile-time error "***missing parameter type***" for the underscore parameter in the implementation
code and I do not understand why.... I thought that the scala implicit typing
should do the necessary but obviously I am wrong.

Can anybody help? I am probably doing something stupid, but for the life of me I cannot see what.

Regards,
Rick

This is my service interface (API) definition (in the file MyService-api/MyTestService.scala):

```
trait MyTestService extends Service {

def myTest2(cmd: String) : ServiceCall[NotUsed, String] // (abstract) method definition

override final def descriptor = {                       // Service Descriptor
        import Service._
        named("myTest2")                                // service name
        .withCalls {                    
        pathCall("myTest/:cmd", myTest2 _)              // will become the REST URI
        }
        .withAutoAcl(true)
    }
}
```

and this is the implementation definition (in the file MyService-impl/MyTestServiceImpl.scala) that is causing the compiler error:

```
class MyTestServiceImpl extends MyTestService {
    // this is where the error happens....
    override def myTest2() = ServiceCall { _ => Future.successful("Hi MyTest2 user") }  
                                           ^
                                           ^ 
                                         (here)
}
```

Comment: Is it going to cause problems if you will define missing parameter type?

Answer (score 2):

It would be good if you pasted the exact error output, but the problem is that you defined `myTest2` to be a method that takes a `String`, ie `def myTest2(cmd: String)`, but then you've implemented it as a method that takes no parameters, ie `override def myTest2()`. Change it to `override def myTest2(cmd: String)` and that will fix your problem.

The reason for the specific error you're getting is that because you're not actually overriding the `myTest2` method as defined, the Scala compiler can't infer the type of `ServiceCall` that you're meant to be returning, and hence can't infer the type of the parameter in the lambda that you're passing to `ServiceCall`.

Comment: ta James - this was indeed the problem.